# How to store the returned value of external script to a variable?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

The following does not set anything globally or to the context but it returns an object when evaluated:

```
(function(){return {a: 1}})()
```

How can I include it as a `scriptfile.js` and get that return value to a variable?

I've also tried with `requirejs` like this:

```
// <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.2.0/require.min.js'></script>

requirejs.config({
    enforceDefine: true,
    paths: {
        scriptfile: 'scriptfile' // without extension
    },
    shim: {
        scriptfile: {
           // exports: "..."  // otherwise works in case of setting to context 
        }
    }
})
require(['scriptfile'], function (module) {
        console.log("module: " +module.toString())
   },
   function (err) {
        console.log("error: " +JSON.stringify(err))
        var failedId = err.requireModules && err.requireModules[0]
        requirejs.undef(failedId)
   }
)
```

but if there is nothing exported in the context so I just get the `nodefine` error.

Comment: You cannot access a selfcalling function. Thats why selfcalling functions exist. Do var o=(function(){return{a:1}})(); for accessing it

Comment: *Not at all.* Please take a look at the [requirejs docs on how to define a module](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define) aka. export things from your script